# Is there data for natural background radiation measurement?

Tags: particle-physics, radiation, measurements, elementary-particles, data

I am looking for raw data of alpha/beta/gamma particles natural background long-term measurement (preferably day by day or second by second for at least a few weeks), but cannot find any. I would be very thankful if somebody can share links to such information.

Comment: I think the difficulty is your "long term"  . There is no reason to continually monitor backround radiation except in specific locations  for specific regions (experiments in particle physics do that, but the background is a complicated one by all the instrumentation there)

Comment: What long term patterns do you expect to see in such data considering that these particles are due to cosmic rays mainly? I would suggest looking for data on terrestrial gamma ray flashes which are produced due to lightning. Variability in such data may be more pronounced. Fermi GBM may also be relevant.

Comment: @annav I thought that way too, but was interested if there are such data available.

Comment: You'll need to specify a place or a collection of places (e.g. "my kitchen counter" or "my own daily life living in XYZ city"). There isn't just one background radiation rate because there isn't just one background. Soil and building material composition, solar activity and exposure thereto, etc, will affect results.

Comment: @Newbie I don't know about patterns, was interested in general to see if there are such kind of researches and after that thinking about patterns etc, tyvm for suggestion, will definetily check  gamma ray flashes and Fermi GBM

Comment: @gs I understand that, I am interested to see this data at least somewhere

Comment: @KostyaKomless Also Google WACCM-X (https://www2.hao.ucar.edu/modeling/waccm-x) and background radiation, you may find some results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Government agencies routinely monitor ambient radioactivity in many locations all around the world. A simple web search gave me [this data from Europe](https://data.jrc.ec.europa.eu/collection/id-0117) as a first hit --- is that what you are looking for?